# Wordpress htaccess custom redirection using internal rules

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, permalinks

I am using wordpress GeoDirectory plugin, need to modify the htaccess rule

Currently category url is opening at
http://swadeshisetu.in/bundesverband/speaker/location/berlin-1/
Need to open url like http://swadeshisetu.in/bundesverband/city/berlin-1

using internal htaccess rule

I have used

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /bundesverband

RewriteRule ^city/(.*)$ /bundesverband/license.txt/ [L]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /bundesverband/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

It opens the txt file but when I replace it with wordpress page url it gives 404 everytime

Comment: You will have to use WP rewrite API for this, not the .htaccess rules

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try following, based on your shown samples only.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(/bundesverband)/city/(berlin-1)/?$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %1/speaker/location/%2 [L]
```

In case you want Generic rule and anything could come in place of `bundesverband` and `berlin`.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(/[\w-]+)/city/([\w-]+)/?$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %1/speaker/location/%2 [L]
```